# container is positioned from bottom all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, containers

Can anyone suggest me please an efficient way to make one container to stick out from bottom of the browser window and be positioned :relative, be scrollable

Can I do it in pure CSS or there is a javascript/jquery for that?

Comment: you want something like sticky footer?

Comment: What do you mean by "scrollable"? The content of the container should be subject to mouse wheel and that stuff?

Comment: Hi, imagine container that is displayed at the bottom of the page when page loads and on every screen resolution should stick out on 100px from the bottom. You can scroll content of the whole page
It is simply positioning container but way is the best to do it I do not know

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as far as I know you can only do this using JS.

You can get coordinates of the element to which you want to stick, and position it manually. You can update it by "scroll" event using jquery

Comment: Hello, is it something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395046/fixed-position-from-browser-bottom-at-page-load-scroll-jquery-isotope-containe?rq=1

or there is a better script for that?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with scrollable exactly? 
If you want an element to be fixed at bottom use "position:fixed;bottom:0;" the element will stay at bottom even when scrolling the window.

Comment: Hi, I want container that is not a footer to stick out just a portion of it. When you open your browser it should be at the bottom of the page(sticking out on 100px) and you can scroll down the content of entire page.

Comment: Well by your description this css style for the container with ID "fixed_container" should work:

#fixed_container {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:100px;
}